# How to determine the element type of slice interface{}?

Tags: go

I have the following code to double the slice.

```
func doubleSlice(s []int) []int  {
  t := make([]int, len(s), (cap(s) + 1) * 2 )
  for i := range s {
    t[i] = s[i]
  }
  return t
}
```

I want to make the func to double any type of slice. And I need to know the element type first.

```
func showInterfaceItem(s interface{}) interface{} {
  if reflect.TypeOf(s).Kind() != reflect.Slice {
    fmt.Println("The interface is not a slice.")
    return
  }

  var t interface{}
  newLen := reflect.ValueOf(s).Len()
  newCap := (cap(reflect.ValueOf(s).Cap()) + 1) * 2
  t = make([]reflect.TypeOf(s), newLen, newCap)

  return t
}
```

The `reflect.TypeOf(s)` return the type of interface{}, not the type of element. How can I get the element type of slice interface?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you have tried? You are returning values in a function that has no return vars? `func showInterfaceItem(s interface{})  ({{something here}}) {`

Comment: I want to implement autocheck the element type. If `s` is `[]int`, `t` is `[]int`. If `s` is `[]float32`, `t` is `[]float32`.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question... Your function will not compile. It you are returning a value `return t` but there is no return value from you're function

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `reflect.TypeOf(s).Elem()`
to get the type of element of slice.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func doubleSlice(s interface{}) interface{} {
    if reflect.TypeOf(s).Kind() != reflect.Slice {
        fmt.Println("The interface is not a slice.")
        return nil
    }

    v := reflect.ValueOf(s)
    newLen := v.Len()
    newCap := (v.Cap() + 1) * 2
    typ := reflect.TypeOf(s).Elem()

    t := reflect.MakeSlice(reflect.SliceOf(typ), newLen, newCap)
    reflect.Copy(t, v)
    return t.Interface()
}

func main() {
    xs := doubleSlice([]string{"foo", "bar"}).([]string)
    fmt.Println("data =", xs, "len =", len(xs), "cap =", cap(xs))

    ys := doubleSlice([]int{3, 1, 4}).([]int)
    fmt.Println("data =", ys, "len =", len(ys), "cap =", cap(ys))
}
```

The output will be:

```
data = [foo bar] len = 2 cap = 6
data = [3 1 4] len = 3 cap = 8
```

Check it in: [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/yDOHaQXowK)

Comment: The `reflect.MakeSlice()` and `reflect.Sliceof()` is what I need. With them, I implement what I plan.

Answer (score 0):

This is doable in golang and takes me whole day to discover the pattern.

Firstly, we want to get a pointer of slice to make gorm happy, which is has type "*[]Obj". To achieve that in golang, we can create a make wrapper like so:

```golang
func makeWrapper(cap uint) interface{} {
    arr:= make([]Sth, 0, cap)
    return &arr
}
```

Notice that, we can't directly reference the maked value, which might be the book keeping data need to have a stack space to store.

```golang
//Not working example
func makeWrapper(cap uint) interface{} {
    return &(make([]Sth, 0, cap))
}
```

And as the answer before, the `reflect.MakeSlice(reflect.SliceOf(typ), 0, capacity).Interface()` returns `interface{[]Sth}`. (the `typ` here is refer to `reflect.TypeOf(Sth{})`, which equiv to `typ == reflect.TypeOf(v)`)

Thus we need to create a return object of `*[]Sth` and the value inside is a slice `[]Sth` with capacity. After understanding the objective, we can have this code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "reflect"
)

type Sth struct {
    a, b string
}
func main() {
    af:= createSlice(Sth{})
    arr := makeWrapper(10).(*[]Sth)
    println(reflect.TypeOf(arr).String())

    // equiv to makeWrapper, but we do it via reflection
    arr = af(10).(*[]Sth)
    println(reflect.TypeOf(arr).String())
}

func makeWrapper(cap uint) interface{} {
    arr:= make([]Sth, 0, cap)
    return &arr
}

func createSlice(v interface{}) func(int) interface{} {
    var typ reflect.Type
    if reflect.ValueOf(v).Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
        typ = reflect.ValueOf(v).Elem().Type()
    } else if  reflect.ValueOf(v).Kind() == reflect.Struct {
        typ = reflect.TypeOf(v)
    } else {
        panic("only support instance of struct or pointer of that instance")
    }

    return func(capacity int) interface{}{
        // create the outer object saves our slice
        outerObj:=reflect.New(reflect.SliceOf(typ))
        // create the slice and save it to return
        outerObj.Elem().Set(reflect.MakeSlice(reflect.SliceOf(typ), 0, capacity))
        // retrive the interface of outer object
        return outerObj.Interface()
    }
}
```